What are the in-game effects of the Blob infection on the player?
This question contains some spoilers for the internal lore of Cataclysm: Dark Days Ahead, so if you want to avoid those and experience the lore in the game yourself, steer clear. This lore is also gathered from the current stable release (0.H).
"The Blob", which XEDRA scientists refer to as "XE037", is the entity in the lore of Cataclysm: Dark Days Ahead that is essentially mostly responsible for the Cataclysm itself. It is implied through newspapers and other lore entries you find in the game that it was accidentally released from another dimension through the portals that XEDRA scientists were experimenting with before the Cataclysm. It serves as Cataclysm's version of the "zombie virus" and is the reason that dead people turn into zombies, as the Blob reanimates their bodies and uses them to try and spread itself through bites and fluid contact. The infection is effectively everywhere on Earth and has already "won" by the time you enter the world - it has infected every drop of water and is present in basically every surviving human and animal on the planet, and causes some of them to mutate and turn into monstrosities. Essentially everyone who is still living is infected with the Blob through the water supply, and anyone who drank tap water before the apocalypse is pretty much doomed.
It's implied throughout the game that the player is infected with the Blob. The main evidence for this is that the player can rapidly recover from even extreme wounds, and has rapid healing abilities, which the game even hints at through some in-game messages, i.e. "you don't feel like a wound could slow you down for more than a day!" However, the player clearly is not fully "controlled" or negatively impacted by the Blob infection like other people are, and has the ability to meet other people in the world who can still talk and interact mostly normally. I'm not even sure if the player knows they are infected in-game or notices their new Wolverine powers.
This leads to my question: in the current lore of the game, why is the player "semi-immune" to the Blob's effects, and are there any other in-game effects of the Blob on the player besides rapid healing? Is it just that the player has a genetic quirk that means they were mostly immune to the Blob's negative effects? Are there other interesting effects that the Blob causes on you as you play the game that I haven't picked up on?
